# How to hide the paste option from menu in UITextField in Swift 3.0?

Tags: swift, swift3, uitextfield

I tried with every answer posted for this similar question, but it is not working in Swift 3.

```
  override func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
   if action == #selector(paste(_:)) {
        return false
    }
   return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain more about your question ?

Comment: @EricAya : check out my edited question with code

Comment: @iDeveloper I want to hide the paste option from the toolbar of uitextfield , while long press selection

Comment: Nisha your issue is resolved? or still stuck??

Comment: it's resolved. Thanks

Comment: great.  keep it up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works!

```
 override func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
        UIMenuController.sharedMenuController().setMenuVisible(false, animated: false)
    }

    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
}
```

Comment: You have told in your question that you are working with Swift 3, and with this signature you cannot override `canPerformAction(_:withSender:)`.

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone looking for swift 4.2

```
 override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible(false, animated: false)
        }

        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
```